# Is a point inside a closed path - SVG Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

How do you determine if a point is inside a closed SVG path with javascript? Why does the following code not work as expected?

```js
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 600, 600);

var p = paper.path("M82.725,37.884l0.777,1.555l-20.391,9.569l-17.714,7.453L27.508,68.212v3.111l-6.997,19.442l16.329,20.996 l7.864,21.019l0.477,13.026l5.658,10.284l4.666,3.886l-2.333,2.336l7.002,0.777v6.219l3.886,10.888l8.555,0.778l-8.555,4.363 l-10.11-2.03l1.016,24.043l2.873,11.73l0.777-2.333l4.667,16.329l3.111-0.778L56.047,350.44l-16.052,32.639l-8.381,19.527 l15.253,11.277l7.083,9.399l49.77,20.129l8.726,4.064l16.917,3.736l10.131,6.222l27.195,6.222l7.799,4.079l17.865,0.284 l16.354,5.292l72.321,17.903l60.463,45.627l18.082,16.633l-2.032-24.106l-34.777-76.215l-12.66-41.99l-1.447-22.556l-6.826-30.328 l-2.851-12.442l5.054-10.108l5.206-14.061l-0.214-10.045l1.555-14.779h7.774l7.002-3.111l-4.495-27.996l-2.593-27.93l4.753-28.06 l8.555-3.241l20.217-3.652l7.002-3.995l42.771-4.837l13.999,6.393h-3.111l0.777,4.666l3.889-1.558l1.555,3.891h-3.109l4.6,32.661 l3.176,27.219l3.111,0.775l18.662,2.271l12.443,0.062l15.078,6.224l12.139,38.105h-31.926l-1.512,6.997l-2.334,0.775l2.334,3.891 l6.998-6.222l-0.777,4.666l0.777,4.667l15.555-9.333l2.332,0.78l10.889,3.886l-2.336-6.221l3.414,18.664l-8.057,45.126l-4.213,55.97 l-10.584,59.88l7.582,31.108l1.035,24.106L477,579.916h31.105V36.33l-14.777,6.522L442.004,58.88l-24.107,9.636l-32.663,5.032 l-41.993-11.557v-2.333l-45.104-13.219l-9.268-6.761L250.7,25.982L145,20.084L103.72,31.058L82.725,37.884z");

p.isPointInside(165,100); // returns false, but when I draw a circle at that point, it is clearly inside the path.
```

Comment: looks like a bug. Why do you need this anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to answer your problem, or even help much. A bit of googling came up with [this](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/539) issue, along with an observation - the bug seems to be affected by whether you're using floats or integers.

I've put your code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/4yruT/), and it seems like they're right, though in your case, using the decimals makes it work, not break. Perhaps you could use this nugget of information to skirt around the issue somehow.

Credit goes to the creator of the issue on github.

Comment: To make matters more unclear, I've added a mousemove event to your path, changing the color whenever the pointer is inside based on the results of the isPointInside call. The results are... interesting. Here's the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/7A8C8/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this other [issue](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/538), which might be the cause of your problem.

It has been resolved in version 2.1.1. You can get the updated code from this [branch](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/v2.1.1). Updating Raphael from it solved this problem for me.