# Recognize point(x,y) is inside svg path or outside

Tags: javascript, svg

I have closed SVG path that is the province of the country.

How to recognize point(x,y) is inside SVG path or outside by javascript?

Comment: You may try and check this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525729/is-a-point-inside-a-closed-path-svg-javascript

Comment: I cant't use raphael or other library.

Comment: here is one solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427394/how-to-know-if-any-x-or-y-point-is-on-svg-path?noredirect=1#comment75885167_44427394

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call document.[elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint). If the position is in the path then it will return that element. If the path is not filled then you may need to adjust the [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property so that it works properly.

Comment: This does not work in IE nor Edge. It will just return the entire SVG.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427394/how-to-know-if-any-x-or-y-point-is-on-svg-path?noredirect=1#comment75885167_44427394

Comment: @Hack5 You need to call it on the element using the mask, not the mask.

Answer (score 10):

For [`SVGGeometryElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement), which includes paths and the basic shapes, there are

- [`SVGGeometryElement.isPointInStroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInStroke) and
- [`SVGGeometryElement.isPointInFill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill).

They return whether the given point is in the stroke respective in the fill, just as the name suggests.

Example:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById("your-svg");
const path = document.getElementById("your-path");

// SVGPoint is deprecated according to MDN
let point = svg.createSVGPoint();
point.x = 40;
point.y = 32;

// or according to MDN
// let point = new DOMPoint(40, 32);

console.log("In stroke:", path.isPointInStroke(point)); // shows true
console.log("In fill:", path.isPointInFill(point)); // shows false
```

```html
<svg id="your-svg" width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 10, 150 110 S 80 190, 40 140 Z" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="5" fill="#adff2f77" id="your-path"/>
  
  <!-- only to show where the point is -->
  <circle id="stroke-point" cx="40" cy="32" r="2.5" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Besides being more descriptive than `Document.elementFromPoint()` those functions handle stacked elements and pointer events correctly. Note that the above example already contains the small circle laying over the path at the requested point. It is not or only hardly possible to check this case with `Document.elementFromPoint()`.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById("your-svg");
const path = document.getElementById("your-path");

console.log("In stroke / fill:", svg.ownerDocument.elementFromPoint(40, 32) == path);
```

```html
<svg id="your-svg" width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 10, 150 110 S 80 190, 40 140 Z" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="5" fill="#adff2f77" id="your-path"/>
  
  <!-- only to show where the point is -->
  <circle id="stroke-point" cx="40" cy="32" r="2.5" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

---

**Edit**: Thanks to @Arlo who pointed out that the point representation object to use is not clear. MDN is using a [`DOMPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) (or [`DOMPointInit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMPointInit)). Chrome assumed to get an [`SVGPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint) which is deprecated according to MDN.

Note that the support on <del>Edge and</del><sup>1</sup> Internet Explorer is unknown at the moment (according to MDN).

---

<sup>1</sup>According to MDN Edge ≥79 supports both, `isPointInStroke()` and `isPointInFill()`.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'isPointInFill' on 'SVGGeometryElement': parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGPoint'.`

Seems Chrome is expecting something other than what MSDN is saying.

Comment: @Arlo Thank's for pointing this out. I changed my answer, this should now work in Chrome (not tested, I don't use Chrome).