# Is it possible to determine whether a shape is under a certian mask in SVG by JavaScript or even CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have many `<rect>` inside a `<g>` tag in my SVG.

And the `<g>` group is under a circle mask.

The result looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like to know, whether one `<rect>` is inside mask or not, for example:

This `rect` is inside the mask:

[image: inside mask]

This `rect` is outside the mask:

[image: outside mask]

This `rect` is half inside, half outside.

[image: half]

I want to assign different styles to them according to there masking status. For example:

For the shapes inside the mask, I want to add class `.inside` to them.
For the shapes outside the mask, I want to add class `.outside` to them.
For the shapes half inside the mask, I want to add class `.half` to them.

Currently, I can only calculate by using coordinate functions but what if the mask is not a circle?

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Not in a mask. But you can test whether a point is inside a path.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788604/recognize-pointx-y-is-inside-svg-path-or-outside

Comment: Sounds inspiring! Thanks Paul

Comment: After doing some research, I found `isPointInFill` is not perfect: 1, it doesn't work on `clipPath` shapes; 2, it doesn't work on shapes with `transform:rotate`.