# d3.js or javascript version of Raphael.js isPointInside method

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, path

I'm doing a D3 project where I need to find if a point is inside a closed svg path element. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525729/is-a-point-inside-a-closed-path-svg-javascript) which would be helpful if I were using Raphael, but I'm not. Is there an equivalent method in javascript or d3.js I can use?

ex: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.isPointInside

Comment: if this is true, can anyone help with ideas for writing my own?

Comment: The collision detection used in the word cloud generator (see [here](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/about/)) is probably a good place to start.